# Can I skip header row while merging CSV files using MsConcat function of Azure Data Lake Store?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-lake

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.filesystemoperationsextensions.msconcat?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.2.0) is the function that I am using:

```
public static void MsConcat (this Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.IFileSystemOperations operations,
                             string accountName,
                             string msConcatDestinationPath,
                             System.IO.Stream streamContents,
                             Nullable<bool> deleteSourceDirectory = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using MsConcat there is no way to skip header rows. MsConcat operates at the file level and has no notion of a "row". It merely concatenates contents of the files at the byte level.

The row concept only comes into picture when the contents of the file are interpreted with something like U-SQL or Scala. Therefore, you find the constructs to skip header rows there.

Comment: That is what i thought too.Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Amit's answer from a U-SQL point of view: The built-in `Extractors.Csv()` provides an option to skip leading rows and the outputter can add a new header row. If your data format corresponds to this, here is a pseudo code sample:

```
@data = EXTRACT a int, b string // ... or whatever your CSV schema is
        FROM "/filestobeconcatenated/{*}" // provide the file set to the files you want to concat
        USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1); // skip header row. Maybe add other parameters

OUTPUT @data 
TO "/concatenated.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```